# Check if there is a particular value in column in given time window in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas

`enter code here`I have the following Pandas data frame:

```
id date       event 
01 2000-01-01 start
01 2000-01-02 a
01 2000-01-03 a
01 2000-01-04 b
02 2000-02-01 start
02 2000-02-10 a
02 2000-02-11 a
03 2000-01-05 start
03 2000-01-08 b
03 2000-02-05 a
03 2000-02-15 a
04 2000-04-07 start
```

I'd like to know which are the `id`s where there is a `b` event in the 5-day time window starting from the `start` event (`start` is always the first in the event sequences belonging to a particular user).

What is the proper query for the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) of the "start" and "b" per "id", then filtering the rows where difference is below or equal to 5 days using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and getting the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) matching ids:

```
threshold = '5days'

m1 = df['event'].eq('start')
m2 = df['event'].eq('b')

ids = (df[m1].merge(df[m2], on='id')
         .loc[lambda d: d['date_y'].sub(d['date_x']).le(threshold)]
         ['id'].unique().tolist()
      )
```

Output: `['01', '03']`

*NB. if there a multiple "b", the id will match is any of them is within the 5 days threshold.*

Intermediate `merge`:

```
df[m1].merge(df[m2], on='id')

   id     date_x event_x     date_y event_y
0  01 2000-01-01   start 2000-01-04       b
1  03 2000-01-05   start 2000-01-08       b
```